# HTML textbox and text on the same line using Bootstrap or CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I put an HTML textbox on the same line as some text? Here's the example I'm working with: http://www.bootply.com/FhlyLoLMNv

```html
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit <input type="number" id="downtime" class="form-control" style="width:90px" min="1" max="120" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="0"> aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
    <a id="delayed_logoff_help" class="pointer" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="focus" data-content="Donec consectetur suscipit orci, fringilla rhoncus erat tristique vel. Phasellus sagittis dapibus fermentum. Donec posuere erat et mi tincidunt, vitae ultricies turpis pellentesque. Morbi volutpat neque lorem, eget luctus leo elementum sed. Cras cursus velit mi. Quisque et vulputate est, gravida elementum urna.">What's this?</a>
</div>
```

```js
$('#delayed_logoff_help').popover()
```

I need this to work for both desktop and mobile rendering. I've been able to get this to work on desktop but adding `class="form-inline"` to the outer `<div>`, but it does not work for mobile rendering: http://www.bootply.com/G5ZzJ8imG8 (you have to click the mobile preview button to see the rendering flaw).

```html
<div class="form-inline">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit <input type="number" id="downtime" class="form-control" style="width:90px" min="1" max="120" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="0"> aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
    <a id="delayed_logoff_help" class="pointer" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="focus" data-content="Donec consectetur suscipit orci, fringilla rhoncus erat tristique vel. Phasellus sagittis dapibus fermentum. Donec posuere erat et mi tincidunt, vitae ultricies turpis pellentesque. Morbi volutpat neque lorem, eget luctus leo elementum sed. Cras cursus velit mi. Quisque et vulputate est, gravida elementum urna.">What's this?</a>
</div>
```

```js
$('#delayed_logoff_help').popover()
```

Is there a way to get this to work on mobile also?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: Could not get this to work properly with the StackOverflow code editor. Still have to rely on the external site for now.

Comment: We're just looking for some code. Not that hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `form-inline` class from the div and setting the input style to `display: inline` and `width: auto` worked for me:

```
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit <input style="display: inline; width: auto;" type="number" id="downtime" class="form-control" min="1" max="120" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="0"> aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
    <a id="delayed_logoff_help" class="pointer" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-trigger="focus" data-content="Donec consectetur suscipit orci, fringilla rhoncus erat tristique vel. Phasellus sagittis dapibus fermentum. Donec posuere erat et mi tincidunt, vitae ultricies turpis pellentesque. Morbi volutpat neque lorem, eget luctus leo elementum sed. Cras cursus velit mi. Quisque et vulputate est, gravida elementum urna.">What's this?</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this on your css :

```
div{
    display : inline-flex;
    align-items : center;
    flex-wrap : wrap;
}
```

But i'm not sure it's what you want for the mobile part

Answer (score -2):

Seems like you might need to use Bootstrap and setup a responsive grid for mobile view.

Comment: How would a grid help? I want it to be on the same line. I don't want to separate content. Can you explain?